# The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider ..." could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I published my website using visual studio publish option to my host.

my host uses asp.net 4.5.1 framework.

it works fine in local but after I published it, it gave this error.

[image]

my local visual studio solution folder contains a folder named packages and it contains some files is it related to error?

This is my config file(other lines omitted for the sake of clarity):

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for upvote, please guide me

Comment: Please dont use image, but type the compilers line.

Comment: Are you running with full trust in the hosting environment? Also, to get the full, detailed error message, use a browser on the server hosting the website and browse to `http://localhost/[Site]`. You'll get the full error message. Failing that, change your web.config as described on the error page

Comment: [site] what should this be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider" could not be located](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Answer (score 11):

The assembly version in the bin folder must match the version indicated in the `compilers` section of `web.config` file.

This error happens to me when i update the server bin folder. Because the package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` was updated i needed to update the `compilers` section of `web.config`too.

It can be done by simply updating the version attribute on the below example or replacing by entire section with the developer version.

```
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

Doesn't require IIS restart.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Project > Properties.
in "Package/Publish Web" tab and in "Items to deploy(applies to all deployment methods)" section and select "All files in this project folder" from drop down list and then Publish your Web Application again,

Hope Helpful.