# IIS 7 unable to find Microsoft.CodDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, c#-6.0

So when deploying our web service using a customized build configuration, after deploying I get the error:

> The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, could not be located.

when trying to browse the site. Looking in the bin\~configurationName~ folder, I can find the specified DLL just fine though. The error is referencing these lines in my web.config:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Odd thing is when building/deploying for Debug on the same server, I don't run into this issue and everything seems to work fine (which leads me to believe this error exists with my project configuration, not the deployment server). The configuration I'm building for when getting this error is our custom defined QA config, which outputs to bin\QA, so I'm wondering if there's something special I need to do to get the ASP.NET compiler to look at special output folders?

Comment: Okay so looks like I needed to put these files in bin\ only, without the build config subfolder. Made those changes and all is good now. So anyone in the future with this issue, make sure all libraries end up in the site's bin\ folder instead of bin\~config~.

Comment: You can post that as an answer and then accept it, to make it clear your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was caused because I had nested all the assemblies for the site under a folder with the configurations name like you would do in a console/windows app (e.g. 'bin\Debug'). For web applications, the assemblies do *not* get nested under a config folder (e.g. they should go in 'bin\').

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

The deployment solution for a longer term is avoid using Roslyn for the moment.

The problem is that you are using **Roslyn Compiler** and references on IIS. Roslyn is still not having full support at many deployment servers.

Solution is to **remove Roslyn** as this won't affect project functionality!

I wrote similar answer to another question that is related to almost this kind of problem. Take a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668206/1436594