# change output path of MVC x64 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ever since I've changed my MVC 4 project output path,
any changes I make to my `Controller` are not reflected.

When I try to debug my `Controller` with a breakpoint, it doesn't hit and I get

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

### UPDATE

So I've deleted the old bin folder and re-run the application. I've got the following error
[image]
I've followed the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs) and now I get
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that IIS is still looking at the old output path. If this is the case Visual studio is launching IIS Express by it self and I don't know how to configure it

Comment: You can configure if IIS Express is launched by going to **Properties** of the web app project and then the **Web** section. There's this **Servers** part which specifies where Visual Studio expects the app to be deployed.

Comment: The second error (could not load MvcApplication) occurs when the server cannot find the binary containing the application type. It is usually because the application has not been built yet. IIS should be pointed to a directory that contains `Global.asax` file and **inside** this directory there should be a `bin` directory with all the binaries. If it's not like this, something is not configured right.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter issues like this, I do the following:

- close Visual Studio
- stop the IIS webapp/website (if not running on IIS Express)
- delete `bin` and `obj` folders
- start Visual Studio
- rebuild

This usually helps with all kinds of issues that sometimes occur.

It seems that there's two different version of binaries at your project. By deleting the binaries, you might find out what the real issue is.