# WCF application under ASP.NET MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 application at root (http://my.site.com/) and I want to add a WCF application under there (http://my.site.com/svc/).

The root application works fine now, but the wcf application cannot be started due to configuration error.

> The CodeDom provider type “Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35” could not be located.

```
Line 90:   <system.codedom>
Line 91:     <compilers>
Line 92:       <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
Line 93:       <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
Line 94:     </compilers>
```

Any help?

Comment: Look into this answer: [The CodeDom provider type “Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider” could not be located](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34924103/6741868)

Comment: Do you have two separate web.config files?

Comment: Keyur's solution solved my problem. Thanks! And also thanks Ashley :)