# Breakpoint Warning Visual Studio 2017 Debug C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a web app in ASP.NET MVC using C# in VS 2017.

When I make changes to my code and recompile, all my breakpoints turn into the outline of a circle (instead of a full red circle) and it gives me an error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations

I've read lots of solutions, some tells to delete bin and obj folders, but if I do that I got

> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" inherits="FortuneSystem.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

If I clean and build again it appears something like this:

error
[image]

Then some wrote that I need to delete system.codedom tags from web.config and that gives me the first error.

It's not only that, I can't add new methods in my old controllers because it is like they don't exist

If someone can explain how to solve this, I  will be grateful

Thanks

Comment: Are you running your project in debug mode? Have you stopped IIS Express from the system try and started your project again?

Comment: Please show us the code you are trying to put breakpoints on (be sure to be crystal clear as to which lines have breakpoints).

Comment: Yes to both questions. It's weird because my coworker never get this and she can clean her project without problem, I use a copy of her files

Comment: The breakpoint gave me error with any new method, even the simplest one: public ActionResult orderList()
{
    return View(order.getOrder());
}

Comment: I have the same issue. Notably when I go to Debug -> Windows -> Modules it says "Cannot find or open the PDB file" for my project .exe and yet the PDB is there right next to the .exe in the bin folder?!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing recently happened in our team→

It looks like you changed one or more of the following manually, and the code behind did not get updated.

①Name of the Application
②Assembly name

When you clean your build, your "new assembly gets cleaned" but "the old one" stays in your debug folder and gets loaded when you start debugging. So basically what you are debugging is the old assembly, proved by the fact that even the simplest method does not get loaded.

Edit:A simple reproduction of OP's problem

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the (only) answer. I have the same issue on a clean checkout and yet a colleague has a clean checkout that works perfectly.

Comment: I am 99% percent sure this is the answer in OP's case, judging from the fact that OP gets an error `Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" inherits="FortuneSystem.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`. That 1% I simply do not know

Comment: @PaulColdrey, can you clone the repository to completely new to another folder and see if it happens?

Comment: @PaulColdrey it happens the same to me and my colleague

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - I have done a clean checkout and I still get the same behaviour. All the dependencies seemed to be pulled correctly and the build looks perfect but it can't locate the PDB file that is clearly exactly where is should be.

Comment: @PaulColdrey. I just want to make sure that we are on the same page. Did you do a completely new clone to completely somewhere else?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - correct. A completely new clone with just the source files (no obj, bin, .vs) etc. "Notably in my warning I have a Warning MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "x86" and the processor architecture... ... netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation-x64.exe", "AMD64"" whereas my colleague does not

Comment: In my case I get a copy of my colleague project and without changing a thing it's wrong, we installed the same vs tools, our PC is the same model and I am the one who gets the error

Comment: @PaulColdrey, in your case isn`t the problem your .NET framework is not up-to-date?

Comment: @Melissa, Another question, are you in Debug configuration or Release configuration? Because simply put in release configuration. Some of the stuff will be optimized away.

Comment: @Melissa, it is different problem which has a solution at this thread→https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs

Comment: I already did that and didn't work, that's why I asked here. Nothing works