# Roslyn Compiler Error on Website project. CodeDom could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, roslyn

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I target my application to .NET Framework 4.6.1. I'm building a Web Site project and there are several class libraries in the same solution.

I can use C# 6 features in the class libraries (e.g. null propagation operator `?.`, but not in the WebSite project), it will give the error

> Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in c# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.

Why is it that I can use this feature in class library but not in the Website? Then, I tried adding the support for C# 6 through the Website menu which will download the CodeDom and the compiler into the `packages` directory and link it in `Web.config` file.

[image]

I can compile and it runs fine on my localhost, but when I deploy to my testing server, I get the following error:

> Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.

How to solve this?

Comment: The following thread might be related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs

Comment: The most upvoted answer there is to remove reference of the `CodeDom` in the `Web.config`. But if I remove it, then I can't use C#6 features in the Website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install or reinstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform - reinstall
```