# Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a project in Visual Studio that won't compile.
It is throwing lots of errors like these ones:

> error CS1001: Identifier expected
>   ; expected
>       error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>       error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

It is complaining about modern C# constructs such as Tuples.
Whenever I navigate to these files, Visual Studio won't mark any error, or mark them for a second before they go away.

If I go to the project properties (in Build -> Advanced...), the language version is set to "C# latest major version (default)".
If I set it to 7.0 or higher to try to gain support for these constructs, when compiling the project it will throw the following error:

> Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.

So it seems to not be accepting a version of C# higher than 6.

It is worth noting that this project is shared in a repository, and none of the other members of the team have problems compiling it.
Therefore it all points to a problem with the local setup of my machine or my Visual Studio, and not to the configuration of the project.

Some things to consider:

- The package "System.ValueTuple" is correctly referenced in the project and set to version 4.3.1.
- The package "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" is at version 2.2.0.
- The target framework for the project is set to .NET Framework 4.6.2.
- My Visual Studio is on its most recent version, 15.8.7.

These are some of the things that I have tried:

- Upgrading the packages "System.ValueTuple" and "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" to their latest versions.
- I've built, rebuilt and cleaned the project.
- I tried upgrading all the other projects in my solution to the same version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers.
- I repaired my installation of Visual Studio.

And yet nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: wheres the code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please look over the Help pages on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your questions give all of the information necessary to answer them.

Comment: If your coworkers' machines are working, and yours is not, then the sensible people to ask for help are *your coworkers*. We have no ability to look at your machine and see what is misconfigured compared to your coworkers; they do.

Comment: @Steve, Tim - it is more of a configuration / environment settings question. I think I included all of the relevant information, versions and config values. I didn't think that including a piece of code that just shows the use a Tuple would add anything of value or help solving the problem. Similar questions with similar info have been posted and answered, those solutions unfortunately just didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Eric - thanks. That's reasonable. Unfortunately that is what we have been doing so far. I only came here as a last resort. I thought the information I posted would be enough for someone to at least point at a probable cause.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have your coworker create a trivial project that they can
   compile (a toy project that uses a valuetuple).  Write down exactly how they did so. 
   Verify that this project works for them but not for you.
2. Uninstall Visual Studio entirely (no, repair doesn't cut it).
3. Install Visual Studio.  Check for update within both Visual Studio and Windows.  Apply all of them.
4. Restart your computer.
5. Try to run the project.  If it succeeds, you've made progress (or are done).  If it fails, you at least have minimal repro.
6. Create an entirely new project, following the same steps your coworker followed during step 1.  (This step is key. The act of creating a new project often fixes this sort of problem, or gives you a new working project that can be diffed with a broken one).
7. Mess around (install the nuget console tools, manually add/remove random packages, and generally poke around).

If all of those steps fail, give up.  By the time you've read my answer, you'll have already burned a full day trying to solve these problems.  Someone might manage to solve your problem, but you can't know whether that will take another 1 day or another 30 days. 
 True, flatten/rebuild costs 1-2(*) full work days, but it's pretty much guaranteed to work (assuming your onboarding process is robust/consistent).  A wasted 1-2 days is acceptable if the alternative is wasting a week and still not necessarily succeeding.

(*) Here, I'm assuming that your onboarding process is efficient.  If it's a mess, document the process so that you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. I thought about the toy project and created it. It was compiling in my machine. However, I probably made it too much of a toy project, since it wasn't even a web application. At that point, however, we reached the same conclusion as you, and decided to start all over since it would have better guarantees and probably eventually save time.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename .csproj to .txt and open with text editor
2. Find < LangVersion >7< / LangVersion >
3. Change to value to 6 and save file with .csproj
4. Reload project in VS

Answer (score 0):

It took me hours to figure this one out. No combination of installing Nuget packages or modifying web.config worked. You need to change the compiler version in your .csproj file.

Make sure your .csproj file is referencing the 2.0 compiler like this:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `web.config` for a runtime compiler option.
Mine had a `/langversion:7.0` in it.

Switching to `/langversion:default` resolved the issue.

This is in the `<system.codedom><compilers>` node.

Example:

```
<compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```