# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Already i am having latest version of `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

How to resolve it?
i am having error as **access denied** not as **could not be located**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider" could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Comment: I am getting error as access is denied,if i get error as could not be located then i have to install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Comment: while hosting it on my iis i am getting error as mentioned above,Runtime error @mjwills

Comment: Then it is a configuration issue with your hosting provider, and you should contact them for support.

Answer (score 6):

I had the VS-2015 Update 3, but the solution for me was to give permission to the IIS_IUSRS user to the folder of the Web Application in "C:\Users\Aurelio\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites"

Comment: Worked for me, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced issue and the problem was this:
DotNetCompilerPlatform's authorization property setting was changed somehow,

so I opened bin folder, right click to open property -> go to security -> allow all permission and apply.

I also did the same thing for Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll and Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.xml, restarted IIS and issue was resolved.