# How to fix the Error PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-deployment

I just write Web service  successfully run on local server but when i Upload the api to web server the following error occur .

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type
>   "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be
>   located.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider" could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Comment: Follow this Link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haris Zafar, you are missing this Infrastructure package in your project.

Enter Tools> NuGet Package Manager> Package Manager Console and enter this command:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` to latest version by downloading it from NuGet.