# Visual Studio 2019 MVC project template doesn't compile

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a stock MVC project using .NET Framework using Visual Studio 2019. I'm bringing in some libraries with .NET Framework dependencies so I am not interested in using .NET Core for this particular project.

I cannot build it directly after template creation. I get the following errors.

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: titan.webtest.2019,
>   Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Dev\BitBucket\titan.webtest.2019\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(39,5):
>   error : The source file for this compilation can be found at:
>   "C:\Users\chalewis\AppData\Local\Temp\c1a9357d-9664-43ff-b620-3e3f9cd6da41.txt"
>   1>C:\Dev\BitBucket\titan.webtest.2019\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(39,5):
>   error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. error
>   CVT1101: cannot open
>   'c:\Users\chalewis\AppData\Local\Temp\a0dlaaod\CSC94F4D0561EB24F8C974FEF312EB3DC.TMP'
>   for reading
>   1>C:\Dev\BitBucket\titan.webtest.2019\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(39,5):
>   error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation.
>   c:\Users\chalewis\AppData\Local\Temp\a0dlaaod\a0dlaaod.0.cs(89,13) :
>   warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
>   1>C:\Dev\BitBucket\titan.webtest.2019\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(39,5):
>   error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. error CS1583:
>   'c:\Users\chalewis\AppData\Local\Temp\a0dlaaod\CSC94F4D0561EB24F8C974FEF312EB3DC.TMP'
>   is not a valid Win32 resource file
>   1>C:\Dev\BitBucket\titan.webtest.2019\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(39,5):
>   error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded
>   from the assembly "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2019\enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll".
>   The task factory must return a value for the "TaskType" property.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Solutions I have tried:

- Creating a .net core web template application. This builds correctly.
- Creating a .net framework web template in Visual Studio 2015. This
  works correctly.
- Running as Administrator, this does not seem to help.

I am unsure what this Microsoft.CodeDom is much less how to fix something associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is related to the default NuGet packages set up for this include a Roslyn package. if you uninstall the package, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, your solution should work. You can see a full explanation of this at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668206.