# Using Roslyn Compiler with MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, containers, roslyn

I'm trying to replace my TFS server with a [Windows Container](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/) that will handle all of the builds using msbuild.  The project I'm trying to compile is a C# .Net Framework WebSite that has only a solution file and no project file.  The web.config has the `<system.codedom>` sections needed to target the Roslyn compiler to take advantage of the C#6 syntax however because I'm not using Visual Studio to compile the application the needed files in the bin/roslyn folder never get restored while doing the `nuget restore` command.  Without those files being restored I receive the error

> error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.

Since the build tools are for visual studio 2017 I thought the gac might have the dlls and executables required for the c#6 syntax so I removed the `<system.codedom>` section and try to compile again only to receive compile errors for the `$` for the interpolation syntax.

I've read several blog posts, [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)  [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe), where people have had success just installing the compiler package from nuget however I believe because my solution has no project file the hints and targets that would normally help restore the refresh files in the bin/roslyn folder is skipped.

How can I get msbuild to use the correct compiler and make the required dlls available without having to generate a project file?