# C# extension failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have published my site out to local IIS, but when I launch the site I get the following error:

> the CodeDom provider type
> "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be
> located.

I have built the application on .NET version 4.6. I have thought about building on 4.7.2, but wasn't sure if that would fix this issue.

Comment: Is your web application doing anything with the .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn) SDK?

Comment: Also, does the site work properly in debugging mode, not on a local IIS instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider" could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Comment: @CoolBots yes, it does work in debug, but as soon as I deploy it I get that error.

Comment: @RoarS. I removed the packages and commented out the code that was suggested in the thread, and I got this back `%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ShoeBot.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`

Comment: If you are going to upgrade, go for .NET 4.8. There may be a reference in your web config or csproj that is out of sync with your dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was adding the following lines on the Web.config, that for some reason were not present:

```
  <system.codedom>
   <compilers>
    <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Comment: Mine was the opposite, I had those in there, removing them fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose 1 of 2 ways to add this CodeDom
Using package config or nuget to install as reference to your proj
or using web.config. I prefer nuget option and remove   <system.codedom>