# Can Azure DevOps Pipelines build an ASP.NET Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, aspnet-compiler

I have an older codebase that uses an ASP.NET Web Site (***not** an ASP.NET Web App*) and am trying to construct a Pipeline for it on Azure DevOps.

After running into some difficulty when the process reaches `aspnet_compiler.exe`, I created a simple test solution containing a single ASP.NET Web Forms Site, generated from the template in VS2019. I then created a Pipeline using the ASP.NET template and ran it, which ended in familiar failure. The test solution and the real solution are failing at the same spot, so at least I have pinpointed the problem... unfortunately, I don't know how to address it.

The full log for the build step is at the bottom of my post, but here's where I'm stuck specifically:

```
Project "D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /localhost_51752 -p WebSite1\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\localhost_51752\ 
##[error]WebSite1\web.config(116,0): Error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
D:\a\9\s\WebSite1\web.config(116): error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. [D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj]
```

I should note that this doesn't appear to be related to the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` assembly specifically. In my actual ASP.NET Web Site (not this little test one I'm working with here), this same "`Error ASPCONFIG: ... * could not be located.`" error occurs if the site's `web.config` contains this, for example:

```xml
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.8">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

In that case, it will throw the same error, but about `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` instead. Clearly, `aspnet_compiler.exe` is unable to find my references, but I don't know what's missing -- are the references not being copied somewhere, or is the process not looking for them in the right place, or... ?

Here is the entire Azure DevOps Pipeline build log:

```
##[section]Starting: Build solution
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.166.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
==============================================================================
##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=f1e19740-d1c0-4435-a66d-d2b7ccec211f|SolutionDir=D:\a\9\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\9\a\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_ab00089e-3c64-4607-ad03-57473b1db76f_build_3_0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 8/28/2020 6:48:44 PM.
Project "D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
Project "D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /localhost_51752 -p WebSite1\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\localhost_51752\ 
##[error]WebSite1\web.config(116,0): Error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
D:\a\9\s\WebSite1\web.config(116): error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. [D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj]
Done Building Project "D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\a\9\s\Hello.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Build target) -> 
  D:\a\9\s\WebSite1\web.config(116): error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located. [D:\a\9\s\WebSite1_1_.metaproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.47
##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Build solution
```

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs ? Di you try install `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Sites seem to need a little extra love to work in an Azure DevOps Pipeline, but they can work. Here's where I landed...

1. The Pipeline environment doesn't have Visual Studio installed. Make certain that your *.refresh files are pointing to downloaded packages (i.e. stuff NuGet automatically puts in your packages directory), not to the Visual Studio shared packages directory.

In a new Web Site project, for example, the content of `Bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll.refresh` defaults to:

```
..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll
```

...but should be:

```
..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll
```

2. NuGet has no idea it needs to restore packages for a Web Site because there's no `*.csproj` to tell it so. Add a custom NuGet restore task (where "`WebSite1`" is the directory your Web Site is in):

```yaml
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Restore for Web Site'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    arguments: 'restore $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\WebSite1\packages.config -SolutionDirectory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

3. NuGet won't run the install PowerShell script to put all the Roslyn files in your Bin directory prior to running `aspnet_compiler.exe`. You have to do that yourself with a Copy files task:

```yaml
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Roslyn files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\tools\RoslynLatest'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\WebSite1\Bin\roslyn'
```