# How do I use Azure DevOps pipeline to build an ASP.NET web site?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vs-web-site-project

I am working with an older code and attempting to build an ASP.NET website (no .csproj files).

I've created an pipeline for ASP.NET added some tasks to my .yml:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

However, when I run the pipeline, it fails on the VSBuild task:
[image: VSBuildResults]

The problem appears to be on line 18 where the `-p ..\BOMViewer\` is specifying a directory that doesn't exist.

I may need to follow DJ Grossman's solution later: [Can Azure DevOps Pipelines build an ASP.NET Web Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639769/can-azure-devops-pipelines-build-an-asp-net-web-site)

But for now, how can I specify `-p \BOMViewer` instead of the above?

***Update**
I changed solution to .publishproj from .sln in my YAML per @YashGupta suggestion.  But VSBuild doesn't like the change:
[image]

**Final**

My .gitignore was ignoring the .publishproj file.  Changed that and it worked like charm, per @YashGupta's answer below.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but the official documentation of `VSBuild@1` task shows that the path to `.sln` file should be specified with a backward slash: `**\*.sln` , and not with a forward slash: `**/*.sln` like you're using in your YAML. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops

Comment: @YashGupta thanks for looking at this.  I changed that in my YAML, but it had no effect.

Comment: Maybe try building your website using `MSBuild@1` task instead of `VSBuild@1` task since VSBuild task is not liking those changes? Worth a shot.

Comment: @YashGupta,I tried using `MSBuild@1`, but I didn't get any different results.

Comment: @YashGupta since it is a website, do I need to create a publish profile in the solution itself for a web deploy or a web deploy package (eventually this will be deployed to an on-prem IIS)?

Comment: Currently, the publish is to a FolderProfile, which is then copied to the IIS server manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, for an ASP.NET Website you should be using `website.publishproj` file instead of the `.sln` file to build it. Because Website projects are actually published, and not built (and that's why the `.publishproj` files in this case work similar to `.csproj` files).

Try modifying the value of your `$solution` variable to `**\*.publishproj` instead of `**\*.sln`.

Comment: could you please help me to specify the path of  zip(of build generated by artifact) to feed into an azure web app.