# Problems updating an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I have an application written in aspx. The application, launching it from visual studio 2017 works correctly, using any browser.

But when publishing it, and running it on the server, I get the following error:

```
Parser error message: Could not locate provider type CodeDom "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35".
```

I have tried with all the versions available in the Nuget Package Manager and I always get the same error, changing the installed version.

What I do is publish the application in the directory and upload it to any directory on the server. Enter the ASPX of the project and I get that error.

Is there any way to solve this?

The project was already installed previously, and I just have to update the source.

[image]
The project settings
[image]
[image]

The two extensions that give me problems

I have read in multiple sites that changing the version of the CodeDom, and I have followed the instructions to the letter and it has not worked

Comment: have you tried answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider" could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs)

Comment: I have seen that in the end updating the binaries the problem has solved itself. Thank you very much for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Just need to comment system.codedom tag in web.config file this work for me. like this

```
 <!--<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>-->
```