# How to correctly do Debug/Release builds in ASP.NET Web Api 2 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET Web API 2 doesn't offer the ability to change the output path for different configurations because of a well known bug -> ( [Change Build Output Directory of WebApi Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852630/change-build-output-directory-of-webapi-application) )

What is the way to automate this process to correctly output in two different ways ( one with .pdb symbols and one with clear release build ) ?